# Mongoose insertMany with over 80000 record

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, mongoose

```js
console.log('Starting...')
let data = JournalDetails.find().lean()
    // data maybe over 80000
    JournalDetails.deleteMany({})
    JournalDetails.insertMany(data)
console.log('done Journal details!')
```

but it alway execute two time when call it(1 time) .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rF3f8.png)

Comment: mongoose's [bulkwrite](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite) could be used for your help. But i would suggest to use it with a batch size like 10k per batch.

Comment: could you write sample code use with `bulkwrite` for me ?

Comment: show us how this code is started

Comment: I base on `meteor` , i created method on `server side` and then I call method from `client side` but when I call it 1 time it execute two time .